# Sum all value of row when find a specific word in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to sum all values of one row (there are a lot of column) if there is a specific value in the first column.

Below follow the problem:

[Link with the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f0mC.png)

I want to find API Rheology and then find Cond. Time, with verified this two conditions, sum all values of the row.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a little specificity?  Maybe some sample data?

Comment: `=if(A2 = YOURVALUE),sum(B2:BB2),"")` will work as a formula.

Comment: I added some data to be more specific. Its a link to the image because i cannot post image yet =(

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the value of the first column with an "IF" function, and then if it's true, use "SUM" to find the total.

For example, if your first column is in a1, and your data goes from a1 to z1, than your formula should look like this:

```
=IF(A1="[check value]",SUM(A1:Z1),"")
```

Where you replace `[check value]` with what value you are looking for and `""` with what you want to display if the value is not there. Putting `""` will leave the cell blank.

If you want to be more specific and check if the first column *contains* a value, then you need to use:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("[check value]",A1)),SUM(A1:Z1),"")
```

With the same arguments as before.

If you want to find **multiple** values than you need to use the `AND` function, so your function becomes:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("[check value]",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("[check value 2]",A1))),SUM(A1:Z1),"")
```

This will check if cell A1 contains both strings. If you want to check **two different** cells, then just replace the second A1 with whatever other cell you want.

If you want to find the string within a column of cells, replace the "A1"s with the list of cells you are looking for the string in. e.g. `A1:Z1`

The reason this works is because `SEARCH` returns a number based on where the `[check value]` is found within cell `A1`, or an error if the string doesn't appear. `ISNUMBER` returns TRUE if `SEARCH` return a number, not an error. Finally, `IF` checks if `ISNUMBER` is true or false, and returns the sum of your numbers if true and a blank space if not.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But my worse problem is this:

The problem is that I dont know where the value will be, so I need some how identify this row and sum all the values of this row. How can i make the excel understand this? This last formula will sum from A1 to Z1, its defined, my problem is no defined.

I hope that you can help me!

Thanks!!

Comment: Lets say your last value of a row is in column Z, then just put in the formula of @Magnus in AA1 and drag down till the last row.

Answer (score 0):

The [sample data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f0mC.png) seemed incomplete so I added a few things.

[image: Staggered conditions in SUMIFS]

The formula in AE65 is,

[image: Dynamic conditional range]

This formula looks down column A for the name of the test (e.g. *API Rheology* in AC65) then locates the next occurrence of the reported result section (e.g. *Cond Time (min)* from AD65). Having located that row, it sums columns C:Z.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped! This is it! I need to do this for every test, do you thing that gonna be some lag? Would you advice me to do get another approach?

Comment: There should not be any appreciable calculation lag. This is a very straightforward method.

Comment: Hello, I was on vacation and didn't see if works this code. Now, I tried, but i did not have success. The excel do not understand this code, can you please explain to me? I understood the logic, but did not understand the code. Thanks